# android linearlayout not align right

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a [layout](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/dialog_filter.xml) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:minWidth="600dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:elevation="2dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="end">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/confirm_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="Confirm"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
                android:id="@+id/reset_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="Reset"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/prefer_tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/exclude_tags"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The confirm button and the reset button are supposed to be on the right of the toolbar. However, they are only there unless there is something in the `FrameLayout` (either `prefer_tags` or `exclude_tags`). You can see from the images below:

[image]

[image]

How do I always keep my button on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

> android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:gravity="end"

to

> android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>   android:layout_gravity="end"